# Возникла ошибка с виндой и на экране выходят символы

Tags: windows-10

Всем привет!
Подскажите, впервые с таким сталкиваюсь.
ОС Windows 10
При загрузке на экране выходят однотипные символы в разных местах, антивирусы не находят ничего, реестры исправил(CCleaner).
Периодически выходит синий экран(ругается на ntoskrnl.exe и выдает 
Вот скрин:
https://ibb.co/X3Dwm9j

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Нарушение `DPC Watchdog` - это тип ошибки, возникающей в вашей системе Windows. `DPC` - это сокращенная форма для отложенного вызова процедуры. `Watchdog` обозначает Bug Checker. Проверка ошибок помогает контролировать все процессы Windows, а также фоновые характеристики. Его контрольное значение составляет около `0x00000133`. Сообщение о нарушении появляется, когда Bug Checker ожидает дольше, чем обычно, например, более 100 микросекунд. Если `Bug Checker` не находит ответ, он покажет сообщение об ошибке. В сети советуют проверить диск на ошибки, а так же обновить драйвер (если есть обнова) у `SATA AHCI controller`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть пара ссылок по данной ошибке: [ссылка_1](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/dpc-watchdog-violation-on-windows-10-fixed/), [ссылка_2](https://techloris.com/dpc-watchdog-violation-windows-10/) может поможет.